# Стоит ли разбивать базу данных монолита при переезде на микросервисы?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, микросервисы

Всем привет!
Есть монолит на Java, собираемся разбить его на микросервисы и стоит открытым вопрос, что делать с базой данных. Поясню, например, логически было бы вынести пару таблиц  вместе с микросервисом в свою БД, но тогда нарушатся связи констрейнтов в БД и вместо id придется писать какое-то явное значение сущностей (например номер телефона пользователя, а не его id из соседней таблицы). Или так ломать таблицу монолита слишком bad practice и нужно линковать новые микросервисы к имеющейся БД?

Comment: У вас не может быть микросервисной архитектуры, если вы используете единую БД

Comment: *логически было бы вынести пару таблиц вместе с микросервисом в свою БД, но тогда нарушатся связи констрейнтов в БД* А вот тут следует точно указать СУБД, и желательно даже точную версию.

Comment: а вчем проблема использования единой базы для всех сервисов?  Утопичное, что  каждый микросервис  работает со своей базой данных себя не оправдало. Любой микросервис  использующий справочные данные   уже не может быть  микросервисом.   Мое мнение.  не имеет смысла  уходить  в микросервисы  без  весомейщих  (например,  уход западного поставщика)  причин.

Comment: @Akina, PostgreSQL 13

Comment: @ArchDemon *не может быть микросервисной архитектуры, если вы используете единую БД* Ммм... не могли бы Вы развернуть/обосновать это утверждение? можно со ссылками, но именно прямо, а не косвенно, устанавливающими сию зависимость. А то что-то всё больно похоже на терминологическую неразбериху. Если БД одна, но схемы для каждого "микросервиса" разные (у автора - Постгресс) - то всё в порядке, и они таки микросервисы? Если с БД работает только один микросервис, а остальные шлют ему запросы и получают ответы - это микросервисная архитектура?

Comment: @Труфальдино, микросервис не будет использовать данные из БД монолита, а лишь хранить и отдавать свои данные в монолит. Но на данный момент такие данные являются констрейнтами в таблицах.

Comment: @Akina, если используется единая БД (со всеми её преимуществами), то нарушается принцип слабой связанности. Вы не можете отделить один модуль от другого, вы не можете менять структуру таблиц так, чтобы это не сломало другие модули. Но теоретически можно хранить данные в одной БД и одной схеме, если придерживаться ряду правил, главное из которых - это возможность в любой момент перенести любой модуль в другую БД так, чтобы ни один из сервисов этого "не почувствовал".

Comment: @ArchDemon Как я уже сказал, у товарища Постгресс. Так что имеем одну БД, каждый микросервис использует только определённый набор таблиц из неё, сведённый в индивидуальную для именно этого микросервиса схему в рамках единой БД, причём никакая таблица не входит одновременно более чем в одну схему. Соответственно при отделении микросервиса с ним уходит его схема и все входящие в схему таблицы... обратное при присоединении такого микросервиса. Ни то, ни другое никак не интерферирует с другими сервисами. Что тут поломается-то?

Comment: Единственный вопрос - связи. Без них вообще всё шоколадно. А с ними - просто процесс отделения сопровождается (включает в себя) удалением связей, а процесс включения - созданием связей и проверкой соответствия имеющихся данных ограничениям связей.

Comment: @Akina, поэтому ничего не мешает перенести каждый сервис в свою БД. В конфигурации "всё в одной бд" есть большой соблазн join'инть таблицы разных схем, например. При наличии разных БД так делать становится тяжелее (соответственно легче поддерживать слабую связанность). К тому же, если в общем брать микросервисную архитектуру, то и слой хранения данных может сильно отличаться от модуля к модулю, поэтому в самом общем смысле БД у каждого модуля своя. Если рассматривать вариант со схемами как промежуточный переход от монолита, то решение очень хорошее

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Журнал Здоровье</strike> [эксперты](https://software-architecture-summit.de/speaker/eberhard-wolff/) на [конференции по Архитектуре](https://software-architecture-summit.de/muenchen/) не рекомендуют <strike>так надо собой издеваться</strike> использовать общую базу, но когда мы спросили "а почему?", ответ был примерно следующим:

категорического запрета на это нет, НО, согласно предписаниям архитектуры микросервисов, они не должны иметь зависимостей на внутренние структуры других
систем, а общаться друг с другом или другими системами только через интерфейсы (в широком, архитектурном смысле, т.е. не путать с Java interface).

Так вот, согласны ли Вы рассматривать структуру базы данных как интерфейс, т.е. относиться к схеме базы данных как к спецификации, документировать, версионировать и обеспечивать надлежащую совместимость с предыдущими версиями насколько это требуется?

Не лучше ли довести распилку монолита до конца, а не останавливаться на пол пути?

Если Вы правильно разделите домен на контексты, то и необходимости в общей структуре не будет. Более того, свобода выбирать технологию и структуру хранения данных у каждой команды ответственной за свой набор микросервисов позволяет им работать эффективнее. А не в этом ли и есть смысл микросервисов?